# Console.log exibindo todos os dados do array

Tags: javascript, console

Quando executo o código javascript abaixo:

```
var dados = Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
     dados.push({index: i});
     console.log(dados);
}
```

A saída no console do navegador para a primeira interacao será:

```
[0: {index: 0}, 1: {index: 1}, length: 1]
```

E para a segunda interação será:

```
[0: {index: 0}, 1: {index: 1}, length: 2]
```

Como podemos observar o 'length' é impresso corretamente de acordo com a interação, mas os objetos do Array são impressos em sua totalidade. Porque isto ocorre?

Comment: No seu exemplo me parece que `x` seria `i`.

Comment: Verdade. Foi corrigido.

Comment: Agora me deixou na dúvida também! Nunca tinha reparado isso haha

Comment: Provavelmente porque arrays e objetos são passados por referência, o navegador deve alterar seu valor quando há uma alteração via código (apenas especulando)

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque o que você está vendo no `console.log` é a referência da variável `dados`. Existem duas alternativas para resolver esse problema:

1. Transformar o objeto numa string e depois retorna-lo para um objeto, assim você conseguirá ter o resultado que deseja.

```js
var dados = Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
     dados.push({index: i});
     console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dados)));
}
```

2. Clonar o array antes de exibi-lo no console

```js
var dados = Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
     dados.push({index: i});
     aux = dados.slice(); // clonando Array
     console.log(aux);
}
```

Referências: [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4060176/5314295)

Comment: O problema é que seu eu implemento um setTimeout e dentro dele eu coloco o console.log a exibição é corrigida.

Comment: Como você pode ver no link que coloquei na referência alguns consideram esse comportamento correto e outros acreditam que é um bug do console, porque  ele enfilera as chamadas dos métodos, quando você usa o setTimeout você atrasa a leitura dos dados o que faz ele exibir o resultado que você espera, das duas formas que eu implementei você não precisa adicionar um delay no processo apenas exibe os dados da forma correta.